# Binding a dropdown with year

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to bind a drop down box with years starting from 2008 to current year in C#. How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 13):

You can build a sequence of integers with `System.Linq.Enumerable.Range`:

```
var startYear = 2008;
myDropDownList.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(startYear, DateTime.Now.Year - startYear + 1);
myDropDownList.DataBind();
```

[Enumerable.Range on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)

**Update:** In .NET 2.0 you can implement your own Range operator with an iterator:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Range (int start, int count)
{
    int end = start + count;

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) 
        yield return i;
}
```

Comment: Hi can u tell me what is this System.Linq.Enumerable.Range

Comment: If your project targets .NET 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008) and has a reference to System.Core, you should be able to add "using System.Linq;" to the top of your code to access Enumerable.Range().

Comment: I am using .Net 2.0 (Visual Studio 2005). Is it possible to use it?

Comment: Hi i have used the following. And reached my Expectation

for (int i = 2008; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
{
    ddlDropDownList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}

Comment: That certainly works, though I find the databound version more readable/maintainable. In fact, I suggest defining a GetYears() method to provide an even clearer separation between the logic to populate the list and how it's presented.

Comment: The second parameter of Enumerable.Range is a Count. Not the Max value of the range. You should use Enumerable.Range(2008, DateTime.Now.Year - 2008 + 1);