# Hard Code List of Years?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the scenario.  You've got a web form and you want to prompt the customer to select their birth year.

a) hard code the values in the dropdown list?
b) Grab valid years from a DB table

I can see a maintenance nightmare with copying a set of years hard coded in .aspx files everywhere.

**updated:**

for loop is not ideal (maintenance nightmare and error prone).  The user then has to sift through 120 years that haven't even got here yet.

I still like the DB approach:

```
* Single point of data
* No duplication of code
* Update the table as needed to add more years
* Year table values could be used for some other dropdown for some other purpose entirely for something other than Birth year
```

Simple as that.  No need to go updating code everywhere.   I feel for data that is universal like this, we shouldn't be hard coding this shiza into a bunch of pages which is totally going against reuse and error prone...really it's not pratical.  I'd take the hit to the DB for this.

**Updated** (again...after thinking about this):

Here's my idea.  Just create a utility or helper method called GetYears that runs that loop and returns a `List<int>` back and I can bind that to whatever I want (dropdownlist, etc.).  And I like the web.config idea of maintaining that end year.

Comment: Let me guess that nobody in their right mind here would consider allowing a user to enter a year with a textbox, even if you're regexing to check for 4 digits.

Comment: Why is the for loop error prone/matainence nightmare?

Comment: It's not, if it's in a reusable method.  I was thinking the first poster was going to throw that everywhere in a several code-behind classes that needed it.

Comment: However, if you've got several applications using a method like this, then you've got to go update all those apps (and those apps use the same DB).  Why not use a table.

Comment: Why even make the call to the loop at all?  If you add it into a derived class as in my example, it's just a matter of dropping a different kind of list box onto your forms.

Comment: I don't need to drop custom dropdowns for this, that's way overdone.  We may not use it like this in the future anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C) Use a for-loop to generate the years in a range of your choice.

Something as simple as this pseudocode:

```
for (int i = 1900 ; i < THIS_YEAR - 13 ; i++)
{
    validyears.options.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: I agree. Pick an acceptable starting year and loop to the current.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer.  Just set the range in a web-config, and let it auto-calculate the range for you.

    for(int year =DateTime.Now.Year-LowerYearRange;year<=DateTime.Now.HighYearRange;++year)
        dropDownList.Items.Add(year);

Comment: I was going to say "how many 109-year-olds do you suppose are using the web?", but then I remembered how often my grandmother (who was born in 1896) was unable to have her birth date entered into computer systems.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: We've even got some 88-year-olds on SO, apparently.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9822/age-distribution-of-stackoverflow-users

Comment: @coffeeaddict: It's pseudocode, but most sites don't allow users under the age of 13 to sign up for their services.  Really, you'd have to take into account the current day of the year as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I got that 13 after looking at it, it's the age duh.

Answer (score 2):

Neither - provide a centralized service which can decide which mechanism to use, then the application doesn't care, and you are free to choose hardcoding, sliding window or database mechanisms.

To expand, typically, I would do something like this:

1. Define `IPopulatableYear` interface which has a single `AddYear` method taking an int and constructing an appropriate `ListItem` or whatever.
2. Make `MyYearListBox` inherit from regular `ListBox` implement `IPopulatableYear` (this works for winForms or WebForms)
3. Create static method or singleton or method in your DAL or whatever.

Like this:

```
PopulateYears(IPopulatableYear pl) {
    // Very simple implementation - change at will
    for (int lp = 2009 ; lp < 2009 + 10 ; lp++) {
        pl.Add(lp);
    }
}
```

or

```
PopulateYears(IPopulatableYear pl) {
    // A DB implementation
    SQLDataReader dr = DAL.YearSet() ; // Your choice of mechanism here
    while ( dr.Read() ) {
        pl.Add(dr[YEAR]);
    }
}
```

or

```
PopulateYears(IPopulatableYear pl) {
    // A DB limits implementation with different ranges defined in database by key - key determined by control itself - IPopulatableYear needs to implement a .YearSetKey property
    SQLDataReader dr = DAL.YearLimits(pl.YearSetKey) ; // Your choice of mechanism here
    for ( int lp = dr[YEAR_MIN] ; lp <= dr[YEAR_MAX] ; lp++ ) {
        pl.Add(lp);
    }
}
```

The mechanism is now centrally managed.

Use `MyYearListBox` on your forms and call `PopulateYears()` on it.  If your forms are smart, they can detect all `MyYearListBox` instances and call it, so you no longer have any new code - just drag it on.

Comment: I don't like the +10.  Then you have to go update multiple instances of code with this duplicated everwhere and each could have a different value...very error prone and maintenance hell

Comment: I don't think you are following.  If you have multiple list boxes, you don't want to repeate ANY code.  This is a single implementation in your code - you change it once in one place.  If you have different list boxes with different ranges, this technique can be extended to handle that as well.

Comment: I will add examples that show that this mechanism also handles the database choice of years.  You can even choose different year ranges by database key.

Comment: If I go creating singletons or Interfaces for this my boss will freak out and say I've overdoing it.

Comment: Then make a derived listbox control.  There will no longer be ANY code in your app.

Comment: I know what you're saying but I dno't need to create a custom control just for a list of years.  If you're going to be using it multiple times on a site sure.

Comment: I thought that having a list of years multiple times on the site was the problem.

Comment: It's possible yes. And in that case your solution makes sense. But custom controls are not end all the solution for preventing repeatable code..they can get complex. It just depends. Sometimes it makes sense sometimes it doesn't. I'm thinking about just creating a utility method that returns List<int> of years by running that loop. Then bind my dropdown to that generic list. The utility method could be used anywhere.

Comment: Another problem with controls is taking account of being able to represent existing data outside of any list you are populating.  The amount of infrastructure you should stand up should be in proportion to the problem.  The solution I gave is directly in response to ".aspx files everywhere".  For the first list box I wouldn't stand this up.  For the second I would probably refactor and use a static method in the App object.  For the third, I would refactor and stand up a framework similar to what I give here.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx). I think making DB calls is FAR less performant than Enumerable.Range.

Comment: Also mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508594/binding-a-dropdown-with-year

Answer (score 2):

E) Use a text input box, because that will always work.

(Be sure to validate it, of course, as a number.  Include "Y2K" and "The year World War II started" in a dictionary of years, of course.)

Comment: I think textbox is the worst way ever to do something like this.

Comment: dropdown lists ensure proper values of years are selected with no user error such as typing an invalid date.

Comment: But they are so much more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

How you present the year selection in the web form is irrelevant. It's an interface decision. Your server should not trust the data coming in, and should validate it accordingly. It's trivial to emulate a form submission, so it doesn't matter how it's presented. Heck, you can generate the drop down with javascript so there is no load on the server.

You can validate with a rule on the backend, rather than a lookup.

Comment: It IS relevant.  Exposing the entry as a textbox is 1) error prone 2) forces you to add unneccessary regex validations, 3) forces you to show the user a help label showing expected format to enter.  A dropdown is made for concrete values.  Simple as that.  You should use a dropdown for stuff that's always the same (minus or adding one is fine).  For things like Holidays, months, years, why would you ever prompt a user via textbox when you have to do all sorts of validation for typos.

Comment: I believe this is a valid answer.  A textbox is error-prone, but so is a drop-down, because the user could easily click the wrong item or not select one at all.  It doesn't force regular express validations or any client-side validations at all.  Labels should *always* be present, regardless of the data being entered, for accessibility reasons (and also so the user doesn't forget to enter that information and leave it as its default (wrong) value).

Comment: I'm not seeing what these unnecessary regexes are.  I don't know asp.net, but I'd think you'd need to validate user input regardless of whether you're using a drop-down box or not to prevent malicious input (or to untaint the data).

Comment: The user interface and the backend are completely separate. You cannot rely on the front end to validate the data or force a structure on it. You can use curl to easily emulate a form post, bypassing any front-end controls put in place. Thus, it's the backend that needs to validate, and the backend has no idea if a drop down, text box or something else was used.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're raising this whole issue (and making a bunch of comments), maybe it's within your power to think long and hard this.

For the end user, it's hard to beat the ease-of-use of a text box.  Yup, you're going to get bogus data, but computers are supposed to make things easier, not harder.  Scrolling through a long list of years to find the year I know I was born is a nuisance.  Especially with all those young whippersnappers and old farts who want to enter birth years that aren't anywhere close to mine!

But stepping back even further...do you **really** need to ask the user their birth year in the first place?  Is it **that** important to your application?  Could you avoid the issue entirely by letting somebody else deal with that?  Say by using OpenID, Windows Live ID or Facebook Connect?